# SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Tags: python, syntax-error

I am testing a code with doctest and I want to comment in front of the tests like this:

```
Tests:
>>> part([('Eva', 'Sao Paulo', 21098, '04-12', 1182),\    #False, 1, 0
    ('Ana', 'Toquio', 21098, '06-12', 1182),\
    ('Ana', 'Sao Paulo', 21098, '04-12', 1096)])
    [2, 1]
```

The problem is that when I run the code in the shell it gives me a synthax error:

```
File "/home/user/Desktop/file.py", line 44, in __main__.part
Failed example:
    part([('Eva', 'Sao Paulo', 21098, '04-12', 1182),\     #False, 1, 0
Exception raised:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/doctest.py", line 1315, in __run
        compileflags, 1) in test.globs
      File "<doctest __main__.part[2]>", line 1
        part([('Eva', 'Sao Paulo', 21098, '04-12', 1182),\     #False, 1, 0
                                                                                   ^
    SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't put **anything** after the line continuation character `\`. You have comments after the backslash:

```
... \     #False, 1, 0
```

Remove the comment, the newline has to directly follow the `\`:

```
part([('Eva', 'Sao Paulo', 21098, '04-12', 1182),\
    ('Ana', 'Toquio', 21098, '06-12', 1182),\
    ('Ana', 'Sao Paulo', 21098, '04-12', 1096)])\
    [2, 1]
```

Note the extra `\` after the `part(..)` call to ensure the `[2, 1]` slice is part of it! See the [*Explicit line joining* section](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#explicit-line-joining) of the reference documentation:

> A line ending in a backslash cannot carry a comment. [...] A backslash is illegal elsewhere on a line outside a string literal.

However, you don't need to use a line continuation character *at all* within parentheses, the logical line is automatically extended until all parentheses and brackets are closed:

```
part([('Eva', 'Sao Paulo', 21098, '04-12', 1182),    # False, 1, 0
      ('Ana', 'Toquio', 21098, '06-12', 1182),
      ('Ana', 'Sao Paulo', 21098, '04-12', 1096)])[2, 1]
```

You *can* include comments when relying on the parentheses to extend the logical line.

From the [*Implicit line joining* section](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#implicit-line-joining):

> Expressions in parentheses, square brackets or curly braces can be split over more than one physical line without using backslashes. [...] Implicitly continued lines can carry comments.

Comment: But if i remove the backslash (\) this error while appear:

SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: @ini_9: The code in my answer has no such syntax error. It seems you removed a `)` or `]` somewhere too.